# What cause the error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric'?

Tags: sql-server

I use the query below to convert a column 'Characteristic__c' of varchar(255) into DECIMAL(22,8). The value of Characteristic__c was specified as simply 0.0, but it still cause error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'. Don't know the reason and thanks for help.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(22,8) , Characteristic__c) FROM  [ODS].[dbo].
[Scorecard_Details__c]
WHERE Attribute__c='Employment Duration' and Characteristic__c=0.0 and 
WOE__c=0
```

Comment: `varchar(255)` must be too wide to fit into `decimal(22, 8)`.  Just because a given _value_ is `0.0` does not mean that the space it takes up reflects that amount.

Comment: The issue is just with the WHERE clause, I believe. You'll get the same error with something like: `select 1 from (values('1')) t(a) where t.a = 0.0;`. The fix probably depends on what your data looks like.

Comment: TBH your column names look ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, `Characteristic_c` cannot be converted to a numeric.  In SQL Server 2012+, you can simply use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(22, 8) , Characteristic__c)
FROM [ODS].[dbo].[Scorecard_Details__c]
WHERE Attribute__c = 'Employment Duration' AND
      TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(22, 8), Characteristic__c) = 0.0 AND 
      WOE__c = 0;
```

Note:  If `WOE__c` is a character column, you should use `TRY_CONVERT()` there too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the number in the varchar is longer than decimal (22). I mean a number too high to be stored in decimal. Check your data